# Json разбор Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

Привет всем.
Есть такое:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count":  1
    },
    "data": {
        "raz": {
            "dva": {
                "tri": {
                    "results": 1234,
                    "more1": 5678,
                    "more2": "abc"
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как привести все это в более удобный вид?

```
ArrayList , HashMap
```

Тоесть я не пойму какого вида должен быть `class` со стольки вложениями, чтобы я мог извлечь из всего результата только:

```
private String results;
...

public String getResults()
{
    return results;
}
```

Извиняюсь за столь непонятное изъяснение, не умею пока грамотно все излагать.

Сейчас все выглядит так:

```
public class Json extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Context context;

    private String method;
    private String url;
    private String[] array;

    private String results;

    public Json (Context context, String method, String url, String[] array){
        this.context = context;
        this.method = method;
        this.url = url;
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                String[] s = array[i].split("=");
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(s[0], s[1]));
            }

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, method, params);

            results = json.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {

        Toast.makeText(Main.this, results, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Где что изменить/дополнить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы моежете просто закинуть эту строку в JSONObject и по нужным ключам добраться до результатов

```
String jsonString  = "{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count":  1
    },
    "data": {
        "raz": {
            "dva": {
                "tri": {
                    "results": 1234,
                    "more1": 5678,
                    "more2": "abc"
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}";

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);

int results = object.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("raz").getJSONObject("dva").getJSONObject("tri").getInt("results");
```

Comment: Все оказалось так просто) Помогло! Но можно все же пример с использованием ArrayList , HashMap? Чтобы допустим все вложение сетовало в адаптер, а я потом извлекал нужное. Тоесть из последнего, которое "tri" : {..}

Comment: Хотя тут уже по аналогии. Все, ясно!

Comment: Да, вы по ключу можете доставвать значение из JSONObject и по этому же ключу ложить в HashMap

Comment: @Сергей, вы зря пытаетесь дерево данных превратить в плоскую структуру. Ничего хорошего может не получиться. К примеру, начнут ключи повторяться на разных уровнях?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не совсем понимаю о чем речь, но ключи точно повторяться не будут. Я к сожалению только начинаю осваивать json и если у вас есть какие мысли по этому поводу, я буду только рад