# Помогите пож с JSON в android

Tags: java, android, json, android-sdk, arraylist

Сделал запрос к серверу. Он возвращает ответ:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 462409,
        "items": [
            {
                "message": {
                    "id": 552885,
                    "date": 1376054836,
                    "out": 0,
                    "user_id": 185014513,
                    "read_state": 0,
                    "title": " ... ",
                    "body": "test"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

С помощью такого кода добираюсь к message и записую содержимое в arraylist:

```
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.json.get("response");

                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");

                for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject name  = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                    arrayList.add(name.getString("message"));
```

Каким способом я могу обратится к title, котороя содержится внутри message, и записать ее содержимое в arrayList ?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
          JSONObject name  = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
          JSONObject message = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i).get("message");
          arrayList.add(message.get("title"));
}
```

Comment: Павел, а с вами можно как - нибудь связатся ? Хочу задать вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

[Json разбор Android Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564102/json-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-android-java?rq=1)  Тут довольно неплохо описано как получать доступ к нужным элементам json объекта. Ну а записать в ArrayList это уже не проблема. В вашем случае это `items -> message -> title`